# Calculate Attributes of a Resizing Bingo Card

Tags: math, image-resizing, image-size

Let's say you have a bingo card that's 3000x3000. The tiles of the bingo card are 500x500, and the width of the borders separating the tiles are 83.333 pixels wide. Each row has five tiles and six borders. So `5*500 + 6*83.33 = 3000`.

I want to be able to resize the width and height of the bingo card and then be able to determine two things:

1.) The width of the borders separating the tiles

2.) The width of the tiles

In other words, I need to solve `width = 5x + 6y` where x represents the width of the tiles and y represents the width of the separating borders. Since there's only one equation with two unknowns, it's unsolvable with just this information.

I tried doing the following: If the bingo card is 3000x3000 and we resize to 1000x1000, then we downscaled by 1/3. So I tried assuming that x and/or y was also downscaled by 1/3. However, this kind of assumption didn't hold. The width of the tiles and the border width were downscaled by some other ratio that wasn't 1/3.

How can I determine the width of the tiles and the width of the borders separating the tiles? Is there any other kind of information I can use or is this impossible to solve? In the worst case, I guess I could calculate these values by counting pixels in the image somehow, but if possible I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: There are different downscaling algorithms and the majority of them will not even preserve border crispness. I suggest to extract tiles into separate images, downscale them separately and then create bingo card with downscaled images and border sizes you like.

Comment: Your second equation is that a border is one 6th of the a tile, thus x = width / 6 and y = width / 36